# Align input text icon to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to add an icon to the end of the field input that, regardless of the width of INPUT, the icon always stays on the right, with a small offset from the edge. I tried this:

```
<div class='span6'>
    <i class="icon-calendar icon-large"></i>
     <input type="text" class="datepicker span12 dats" id="dpd2" placeholder="Choose Depart Date">
</div>

.icon-calendar {      
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-indent: 106px;
}
```

and does not work. Help me, please. Using the bootstrap and font awesome

all code [here](http://tourlly.com/begin/)

Comment: Define "does not work".  What's the css on `.span6`? Should be `relative`.  Also, you say position absolute, but don't specify the position with top, right, left, or bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will work.

```
 .span6 { position: relative; }

.icon-calendar { right: 5px; }
```

Comment: Works for me using developer tools.  You sure you're doing it right?

Comment: Look in my ling in question - im upload your changes on server

Comment: You should still keep all of your old styles.  I see you removed  position: absolute; on the icon styles.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In my case, I have a container div (.span6), an input element, and an icon (.icon-calendar). Also, I positioned mine by the left.

````
.span6 { 
  position: relative; 
}

.icon-calendar { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px; /* Pads the icon a little from the left */
  top: 1rem; /* Pads the icon from the top to centralize it vertically inside the input element */
}```

Note: You can play around with the css, especially the left and top properties, depending on the exact place you want to it to be. The most important property is the position property - relative for the container div and absolute for the icon.

For instance, if I want the icon to be positioned by the right as requested in the question, I would increase the left value until my icon moves to the right.

```.icon-calendar { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 14.1rem; /* Pads the icon a lot from the left until the icon is positioned rightwards. 14.1rem worked well for my own case. You can play around with the value to suit you. */
  top: 1rem; /* Pads the icon from the top to centralize it vertically inside the input element */
}```
````